# Should i use a 2x2 ANOVA or a paired t test design?

Tags: anova, t-test

I am writing a proposal answering the question does engagement in synchrony improve empathy levels in those with ASD?

My sample is 1) ASD individuals receiving the synchronous intervention and 2) ASD individuals receiving control condition.

I want to include an asynchronous intervention to ensure it is the synchrony that may improve empathy levels.

Would this test be an ANOVA or a paired t test?

Comment: Both, depending on what your objective is. The ANOVA option is better if you want to find which combination from the 4 total is significant.

Comment: How "to include an asynchronous intervention"?

Comment: I assume by paired t-test you were thinking of two paired t-test, one for the change in the synchronous condition and one in the asynchronous condition. If your hypothesis is that there will be more change in the former than the latter, this won't tell you that. A 2by2 ANOVA will. The interaction of time and condition is the test of the difference in the differences.